# How to create a splash screen for Django web application?

Tags: django, desktop-application, startup

I've created my first workable Django web application, but am puzzled by the lack of documentation or examples regarding the creation of splash or start-up screens.

Am I overthinking this? Is creating a splash screen for my Django web app as simple as creating an initial screen using HTML/CSS/Javascript, or might someone point me in the direction of examples or documentation on how to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/openedx/django-splash How to create a splash screen is probably to much for an answer on stackoverflow.